# Verbs while using if

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

If you want to talk about a possibility or something you would like to be different you can say "If I *were* taller", "If you were faster". You use the verb in past tense. Is it correct?

But what about the following?

> If this app worked in this way, I would like it more.

I don't know but the above sentence sounds kind of weird for me. I don't know if it's correct or not.

Comment: That's OK, because it's past tense form with counterfactual meaning; it presupposes that the app does **not** work "in this way", and suggests an imaginary implication in the absence of this fact. It would be interesting to me -- as a linguist -- to find out what parts of this sentence sound weird to you, and if possible why.

Comment: Thank your for you early reply, I found it helpful. I just go used to using **were** in those kind of situations but I never needed to use it with a verb different than `to be`. As an spanish speaker I get confused when using past tense in a situation that actually never occurred. There's is a specific way of conjugating the verb in this kind of situation.

Comment: @JohnLawler He’s looking for something that’s morphologically distinct as a way of expressing counterfactuality, but finding it lacking in all verbs save *be*.  Specifically, he’s looking for how to express what Spanish uses the imperfect subjunctive inflection (*“Si funcionara/funcionase en esta manera...”*) for in the protasis of a conditional, and the conditional inflection (*“...me gustaría mejor”*) in the apodosis. Some people do say “If only it worked” or “If it were to work” to try to convey that, but we really have no morphological solution beyond *be* — as well you know. He misses it.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to say. Thanks for explaining it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about conditional statements.

The first phrase is using the past subjunctive ("were"). Your clause is setting up a type of sentence called the "second conditional" or a counterfactual conditional.

The second is the same type of sentence, and it's correct.

Here are some helpful articles on wikipedia:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#Types_of_conditional_sentence
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional